# How to limit number of number of categories displayed by categories widget

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, widgets, taxonomy

I am testing my theme against WordPress theme unit test, which states that:

> Large number of categories/tags should not adversely impact layout.

I was able to manage the number of tags but could not help myself in case of categories. Here is the code I'm using to limit the number of tags displayed.
Can it be reused somehow for categories or is there any other way possible?

```
add_filter('widget_tag_cloud_args', 'themename_tag_limit');

//Limit number of tags inside widget
function themename_tag_limit($args){

 if(isset($args['taxonomy']) && $args['taxonomy'] == 'post_tag'){
  $args['number'] = 15; //Limit number of tags
 }

 return $args;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. On what point you want to limit the categories ?

Comment: the_dramatist i want to limit the number of categories being displayed in category widget. suppose i have 50 categories in my blog but displaying them all through the category widget will disrupt the blog's layout. so that's why i want to limit number of cats in cat widget. hope its got cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could show the *Category* widgets as a *dropdown* instead, if you have large number of categories.

I'm not sure how useful it is to limit categories when ordered by `name`.

You might try to order by `count` to display the *most used* categories:

```
add_filter( 'widget_categories_args', function( $args )
{
    $args['number']         = 1;
    $args['orderby']        = 'count';
    $args['order']          = 'DESC';
    $args['hierarchical']   = 0;
    $args['hide_empty']     = 1;

    return $args;
} );
```

but there are other options like `include` and `exclude`.

Note that the *Category* widget uses `wp_list_categories()` that uses `get_categories()`, that's a wrapper for `get_terms()` that uses a `WP_Term_Query` object that contains the following part, in the `WP_Term_Query::get_terms()` class method:

```
  // Don't limit the query results when we have to descend the family tree.
  if ( $number && ! $hierarchical && ! $child_of && '' === $parent ) {
        if ( $offset ) {
            $limits = 'LIMIT ' . $offset . ',' . $number;
         } else {
             $limits = 'LIMIT ' . $number;
         }
  } else {
      $limits = '';
  }
```

The *dropdown* option uses `wp_dropdown_categories()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your new custom widget.
and get category ids of those you want to list and pass them in wp_list_categories function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest unpractical, but still working solution by using the css display: none for categories elements like this:
select first 5 child css:

```
li:nth-child(-n+5){
    display: none;
}
```

Notice that they will still be in the dom, but as invisible elements.